# How can I use composition with methods in ES6 Classes?

Tags: javascript, class, composition

I am struggling to implement composition in ES6 classes! I am trying to understand a lot of things at once and have maybe made a stupid error.

I would like to avoid inheritance using `extend` and `super` for now, and have found this nice example of composition that seems to show what I am after:

```
class EmployeeTaxData {
  constructor(ssn, salary) {
    this.ssn = ssn;
    this.salary = salary;
  }
  // ...
}

class Employee {
  constructor(name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }

  setTaxData(ssn, salary) {
    this.taxData = new EmployeeTaxData(ssn, salary);
  }
  // ...
}
```

In regard to the code below, I would like to use the most simple and eloquent way to make the spin() method available for the objects created by the `Hero` class so it is using a shared prototype. I would like to share this method with other objects that will need it too.

Unfortunately I can't make my code work as the `this.angle` is not referring to to the `Hero` class that it needs to, but the `Spinner` class?

```
class Spinner {

  constructor(direction){
    this.direction = direction;
  }

  spin(direction) {
    switch (direction) {
      case 'left':
        this.angle -= 1;
        break;
      case 'right':
        this.angle += 1;
        break;
        // no default
    }
  }
}

class Hero {

  constructor(xPosition, yPosition) {
    this.description = 'hero';
    this.width = 25;
    this.height = 50;
    this.xPosition = xPosition;
    this.yPosition = yPosition;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.color = 'red';
    this.spin = new Spinner();
  }

  spin() {
    this.spin.spin();
  }

}

const heroClass = new Hero(100, 200);

console.log(heroClass.angle); // result is 0
heroClass.spin.spin('left');
console.log(heroClass.angle); // result is STILL 0, it didn't work
```

Comment: You didn't change the property, therefore it remains unchanged

Comment: You can either inherit from the Spinner class or bind the correct context

Comment: @Vivick you are saying I need to either inherit using extend (which I want to avoid) or use bind()? That is not the eloquent solution I am after. I can't find any examples online of people using new in the class constructor to pull in a method for use in the newly created object... is this too cutting edge or am I missing something? :) There must be a better way to share that spin() method with modern concise syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...the this.angle is not referring to to the Hero class that it needs to, but the Spinner class?

As it should. When you're inside the spinner class, then `this` refers to a spinner object, which also means `this.angle` inside the spinner class refers to an angle property of a spinner object.

You'll probably want spinner to return a new angle value, then the hero object that uses spinner should save the returned new angle value.

```
class Spinner {

  constructor(direction){
    this.direction = direction;
  }

  spin(direction, angle) {
    switch (direction) {
      case 'left':
        angle -= 1;
        break;
      case 'right':
        angle += 1;
        break;
        // no default
    }

    return angle;
  }
}

class Hero {

  constructor(xPosition, yPosition) {
    this.description = 'hero';
    this.width = 25;
    this.height = 50;
    this.xPosition = xPosition;
    this.yPosition = yPosition;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.color = 'red';
    this.spinner = new Spinner();
  }

  spin(direction) {
    this.angle = this.spinner.spin(direction, this.angle);
  }

}

const heroClass = new Hero(100, 200);

console.log(heroClass.angle); // result is 0
heroClass.spin('left');
console.log(heroClass.angle); // result is -1
```

I had to make a few other small changes for this to work. For example, you had a data property named "spin" `this.spin = new Spinner` as well as a method named spin `spin() {`. They were overriding one another.

Comment: Thanks! It works :) I also deleted the constructor as it seems to do nothing needed. My only problem is that eslint says 'expected 'this' to be used by class method (class-methods-use-this)' and gives an error. I am going to base a whole game on this structure and am very keen to have the optimum pattern. Is this how you would solve the problem, and can I get rid of that eslint error somehow?

Comment: OK, i now understand that eslint is saying why bother having spin() as a class with no .this, and suggesting I make it a 'static' function in the class. I can do this, but then I am not really composing objects any more as I delete the this.spin = new Spinner() and access spin() directly by Spinner.spin(direction, this.angle). Any thoughts on this... anyone? Maybe spin() is just a bad example and the technique in this answer is going to be great as my classes get more complex.

Comment: Composing objects is a good thing -- in general -- but don't force it where it doesn't fit. Spinner has only one method and no state being managed; it should probably just be a single ordinary spin function.